# Does the host OS is lost while booting from a bootable USB?

Tags: linux, usb, windows-8.1, sony-vaio, bootable-media

I am running Windows 8.1 on my Sony Vaio laptop and want to run a Linux-based OS from a bootable USB. Can anyone tell me whether my Windows will be safe during and after the booting process or I'll lose all the data, softwares, files, etc. ?

Comment: No, you can access them, but they should not be modified without you doing do so (in for example a file manager).

Answer (score 2):

If you are booting live from a USB or CD you can read/write to the windows partition. Therefore you can screw something up, if you are messing with system files on the windows partition.

You can safely play in the Linux OS environment just don't touch Windows System files or play with the partitions (unless you know what you are doing), and you will be fine.

Comment: crbon i have a Sony vaio svf15218sn. Can you tell me the step-by-step procedure to boot from a bootable USB ? I am  unable to do this as no boot menu comes when I boot with the USB plugged in.

Comment: @user308131 - First off all did you make the usb bootable. Try this software http://www.linuxliveusb.com/. It will give you a simple gui and help you setup the usb drive properly. Leave the usb drive plugged in, then restart the Sony laptop and as soon as it starts booting up again just tap F2 a bunch of times until you get into the bios. Then use the arrow keys to navigate to boot section and then go to hard disc priority change the first option to your usb. Press F10 and then Enter. The laptop should now start rebooting and boot into the usb

Comment: I have done all this using the software unviversal USB installer and have changed all the required bios settings.But the reboot brought me back to Windows. What should I do next ?

Comment: @user308131 - If you pressing F2 repeatedly when the laptop is booting doesn't work. Follow the following steps http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IqkCS0sRz5c When you get to use device that's where you click on your usb and then the laptop should restart and boot into the usb.

Comment: Same issue persists. I followed the video and 3 options come up : EFI USB, EFI CD, EFI Network. I selected the first one,but again the reboot brings the Window OS back. Any help ?

Comment: You might have to dissable fast boot, this should be either in the bios or the windows advanced settings that were discussed before.

Comment: Also might want to try some steps from http://askubuntu.com/questions/385159/ubuntu-13-10-installer-live-fails-to-boot-from-dvd-usb-on-uefi

Comment: No fast boot option ! Nothing seems to work !!

Comment: I'm not sure then, try searching around. It shouldn't be specific to your laptop. In general Windows 8/8.1 handles this stuff differently then in Windows 7 (which I'm more familiar with). Just look into getting Ubuntu running from USB on Windows 8.1 (as Ubuntu will has more documentation and a larger user base that many other distros). Sorry that I couldn't be of more help. ps. might be worth lookin into http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 2):

It should be safe, unless you modify any thing on the file system or partition table. Mostly the file system will be automounted inside linux. You have to be careful if **you are deleting** any files on Windows drive.

Comment: Chandrasekar, I have a Sony vaio svf15218sn. Can you tell me the step-by-step procedure to boot from a bootable USB ? I am unable to do this as no boot menu comes when I boot with the USB plugged in